# Creating Documentation from VB Script Code

Tags: vbscript, documentation, documentation-generation

We have a large framework created using VB Script, which has been created and then maintained for the past few years. This code was initially well documented and all the initial functions and variables and files had good headers in them.

Later in maintainence, the code got obfuscated by the coders not keeping track of new and changed functionality and the final result now in my hands is a code which has around ~600 files and none of them have the proper description of the functions and variables in them :-(

Could someone inform if they have created documents (on the fly types - dOxygen, etc.) for this type of code written in VB Script?

Comment: can you add a link to the vbs files so that we can examine it or include sufficient code from it to have an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago I wrote a script ([VBSdoc](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vbsdoc.shtml)), so I could use Javadoc-like comments in my scripts and generate documentation from them. However, without proper comments it will merely list constants, variables, functions and classes. Not sure how helpful that'd be to you. Also, I have never tested it with a project of this size. I'd be interested in feedback, though, should you want to give it a try.

Comment: I can highy recommend this tool!